# Macro VBA code failing to execute a section of the code without an error

Tags: excel, vba

hi I have used a  macro to record a VBA code my code works fine until the part where the code is supposed to sort 2 columns ,the code just disappear without an error..please note i got this part of the code by recording a macro on that section. I would like to use this code on different worksheets

```
Sub testSort()
'
' testSort Macro
'

'
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis 1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis 1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
         "E5:E661325"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
 xlSortNormal
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis 1").Sort
         .SetRange Range("A4:F661325")
         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply
 End With
End Sub
```

i tried to run the code by sub categories ,i first recorded a macro that just select the part that i want to sort ,i took that section of my code and join it to the main code and it ran just fine.
then i recorded a macro that use data sort method of excel to sort the data i copied that part of my code to my main code as before, and is failing

Comment: `.SetRange .Range("A4:F661325")` missing the `.`  I would start by creating a worksheet variable and use that to qualify all ranges.

Comment: Which two columns? Your code only tries to sort by column `E` (`5`). In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75821989), you tried sorting by column `G`. Is that the other column?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

That is completely dependent on which cell you have selected on that sheet. If your cursor is in cell A1 then it will never select the data which appears to start in A4.

Remove those lines entirely - you should avoid using `Selection` and `Active...` - explicitly name the ranges to avoid problems like this

Answer (score 0):

You get your code to make a selection but then your sort doesn't sort the selection – it looks at a specific range.  If you are trying to sort your selection, try this (but substitute `A1` and `B1` for the actual header cells you want to sort by):

```
Sub trytthis()

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("a1"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("b1"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort ActiveSheet

```vb
Sub SortActiveSheet()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Sort ActiveSheet"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
  
    Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 4
    Const SORT_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
     
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Sheet """ & ActiveSheet.Name & """ is not a worksheet.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range, RowOffset As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet

        With .UsedRange
            RowOffset = HEADER_ROW - .Row
            Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - RowOffset).Offset(RowOffset)
        End With

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 _
                Key:=rg.Columns(SORT_COLUMN), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rg
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    
        If SHOW_MESSAGE Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet """ & .Name & """ sorted by column " _
                & SORT_COLUMN & " in ascending order.", _
                vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        
    End With
      
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```